# What is the current status of SubSonic ORM project?

Tags: subsonic, subsonic2.0

VS2010 .Net4

Is SubSonic still the tool of choice? Are there easier ways to accomplish the creation of a DAL with the stock tools in VS2010?

I need to convert a project that was done with Subsonic 2.03 several years ago and would like to hear opinions on the "right" way to do this.

TIA

J

Comment: Any particular feature you need that SubSonic 2 doesn't provide?  SubSonic is still alive and kicking.  The best place to find out the current happenings behind the scenes are on the SubSonic Google group: http://groups.google.com/group/subsonicproject/topics?start=

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql/1378028#1378028

Comment: @sparks: SubSonic 2 doesn't have Linq support, which can be a big deal.

Comment: My question was prompted by the fact that there seemed to be very little activity on the Subsonic site. I didn't realize there was a google groups location also. 

Still since there haven't been any releases for over a year I thought that it might have been replaced in the community by something newer like EF4.

Thanks for the info.

Comment: SubSonic 3.0.0.4 was released in March of 2010: http://blog.wekeroad.com/2010/03/21/subsonic-3-0-0-4-released

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SubSonic is a fine ORM, but it lacks many features that Entity Framework 4 and NHibernate have.  SubSonic also isn't moving forward as quickly as EF and NH.

It is possible that SubSonic will be the best .NET ORM two years from now, but that seems highly unlikely at present.

There is no one "right" or "correct" answer when choosing a .NET ORM.  NHibernate seems like the safest choice right now, while Entity Framework 4 is a good fit for companies that prefer solutions from Microsoft.  SubSonic 2 & 3 will work just fine in many situations and it may be better for your project to just maintain what is already working.

Comment: I believe that EF is the route I may explore. We are a small shop and I need to optimize my time, Subsonic did that for me but it just seemed to be inactive for over a year.

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

If u stick on MS SQL database, i can said Subsonic is fine and easy to code. But if u need other non MS database, my suggestion is nHibernate. I just switch back to nHibernate from Subsonic.